# Visual Studio 2010 Code snippet

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

i have managed to make a code snippet and its all good, the question is i dont want to use ctrl+k ctrl +S then click on the snippet , instead i want to use a combination of keys to just use the snippet  right away , or at least pressing ctrl+k ctrl + S then another combination ?

is that possible ?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say you're pressing `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S` is because the snippet you added was a *Surround With* snippet, isn't it?

I suggest you installing [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for this purpose. You can easily add all kind of snippets (called ***templates*** in ReSharper), and of course, *Surround-With snippets*.

After adding a template, you can give it the number you want.

Then all you have to do is press: `Ctrl+Alt+J` and you will see the following:

[image: ReSharper templates example]

And all you have to do is press the number of the snippet you want.

For example, if you want to surround some code with an `if`, you press: `Ctrl+Alt+J, 1`.

**Note:**
In this moment, I don't really remember if `Ctrl+Alt+J` is the keyboard shortcut by default, because I have changed many of them, but you can check it in ***ReSharper*** > ***Edit*** > ***Surround With Template...***

Comment: So bad Resharper is not free.. It seems to be really usefull

Comment: @bAN It worths paying for ReSharper! That's only a **very tiny** feature it provides ;-) It lets you run your unit tests in NUnit, refactor your code, and gives you lots of tips about how to improve your code (using var, converting if __ else __ to a ternary operation, nested foreach into a simple LINQ query, etc, etc, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Easier than typing a key-combination is just typing the name+[Tab]+[Tab].  Visual Studio is pretty good at remembering the last ones used to make it even easier.

"f+[tab]+[tab]" creates a for loop snippet.

Comment: How would you do this for the `#region` snippet?

Comment: Typing '#region[tab]' accomplishes the same.  True, it doesn't offer suggestions on preprocessor snippets.

Comment: Okay. I just wanted to know if you know how to do it :/

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet file, you can set up a shortcut element.  Your code snippets are located under(depending on language):

> "\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code
>   Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets"

Under the CodeSnippet\Header\Shortcut section in the code snippet file, type a unique short relevant series of characters.

```
  <CodeSnippet>
    <Header>
      <Shortcut>spi</Shortcut>
    </Header>
```

Typing these characters followed by tab in the code window will insert your code snippet.

Comment: that cant work with surround with snippets as typing would replace the selected code.